# How to insert headers in google spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, google-apps-script

i am trying to add an arraylist as header in spreadsheet. i've refer the google apis, and i am like able to insert row. But now i need to insert array of row in one shot. is it possible please help.

```
 // Create a local representation of the new row.
  ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "firstname", Value = "Joe" });
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "lastname", Value = "Smith" });
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "age", Value = "26" });
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "height", Value = "176" });

  // Send the new row to the API for insertion.
  service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible to insert multiple rows with listfeed. use cellfeed instead.

Comment: hiii mandel thanks for replying back. as i am new to programing and i hardly have hands on C# .Net,so if  u can please explain me with small piece of code as example.

Comment: I dont use C# but I see there is documentation available. Code an attempt and post back if you get stuck. http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r890/docs/folder41/T_Google_GData_Spreadsheets_CellFeed.htm